# regex to see if one specific letter is always followed by another specific letter

Tags: python, regex

I have a word entered by user. I want to check if the word satisfied the following rule or not.

Rule : The letter q is always written with u.

```
user word : qeen
```

the output will be

```
not match with the rule.
edited word : queen
```

one more example :

```
user word : queue
matched with rule. no edit required.
```

Comment: Why regex?  This can be done with string manipulation. If the count of 'q' does not match the count of 'qu' then edit ..

Comment: because regex is always better than string manipulation

Comment: What about "qi", "qat", and "suq"? </scrabbleplayer>

Comment: these are the exceptions for the english word rules. I have to check how can i implement those after this stage.

Comment: @Wooble - "Linq" in C# </coder> ;-).

Comment: @iCodez : lolz. it was about english word rules. ;)

Comment: I was jumping ahead to fixing the problem.. for the issue of checking then regex and string operations are neck and neck.  When the issue of editing is addressed, it is simpler to match and edit in one operation.

Comment: how can we do that in more easier way than explained by tim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> 'q' in 'qeen'.replace('qu', '')
True
>>> 'q' in 'queen'.replace('qu', '')
False

>>> 'qeen'.replace('qu', 'q').replace('q', 'qu')
'queen'

$ python -m timeit -s"import re" 're.sub("q(?!u)", "qu", "The queen qarreled with the king")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.57 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"'The queen qarreled with the king'.replace('qu', 'q').replace('q', 'qu')"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0163 usec per loop
```

Comment: dats nice but then which one is more efficient? to use regex or string operation?

Comment: `replace` is more than 100 times faster than the regex for the example in my answer

Comment: @sam Remember this: "because regex is always better than string manipulation" .. did you mean in terms of maintenance, ease of comprehension or runtime efficiency?  Gnibbler shows that replace (a string manipulation) is faster. Combining exception lists and regex will be a bear

Answer (score 10):

That's a perfect fit for a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
q(?=u)
```

matches a `q` only if it's followed by `u`, whereas

```
q(?!u)
```

matches a `q` only if it's *not* followed by `u`.

So:

```
>>> if re.search("q(?!u)", "qeen"):
...     print("q found without u!")
...
q found without u!
```

Or

```
>>> re.sub("q(?!u)", "qu", "The queen qarreled with the king")
'The queen quarreled with the king'
```

However, what about a word like `Iraq`?

Comment: thats the exception for the word rules. i have to see how can i implement those.

Comment: @sam: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: actually i want to implement all the english word rules on the user entered word. like : http://www.riggsinst.org/28rules.aspx

Comment: OK, what's your question?

Comment: @sam: enforcing those rules is going to be pretty tough.  Many of them are about the connection between how words are spelled and how they're pronounced, not spelling rules per se.

Comment: so my question was to how to implement all those rules and add exceptions to it as well. because adding exceptions for specific rule si a very complex task.

Comment: @DSM : yes I know but I will try to implement 5-6 of those for a word.

Comment: @sam: OK, and which part of that exercise are you having problems with? It looks like you could ask a new question about this (showing the code you have written thus far, what's working about it, and what's not working about it the way you'd like it to).

Comment: yes i will do the same. i got some bit of idea how to proceed now.

Comment: Is this a homework question with a specific algorithm you need to implement? English doesn't actually have any spelling rules, despite what English teachers might want to claim.

Comment: yes it is to implement english word rules on a word or a simple spelling checker with some english rules.